# Picture Box doesn't updates when setting Image object

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I have a problem displaying image object on the pictureBox. I have the following method:

```
private async void scanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var guid = await client.ScanRegionAsync(new Point(0, 0), new Size(200, 200));
    var currentImage = new ImageData();

    while (currentImage.TransmissionStatus != TransmissionStatus.ProcessStop)
    {
        currentImage = client.GetImage(guid);
        if (currentImage.TransmissionStatus.Equals(TransmissionStatus.Image))
        {
            stitching.AttachImageToScene(currentImage.ImageBytes, currentImage.StartPoint);
        }
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = stitching.CurrentImage;
    stitching.CurrentImage.Save(@"c:\stitch.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

and the thing is that picture DOES get saved ok, but pictureBox DOESN'T show it for some reason. 
P.S. I tried Refresh/Update, tried to clone image, tried to make method synchronous - same result.

Comment: Did you try `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` at the end?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same result.

Comment: just for minds relieve save it first then assign to picturebox...

Comment: well, this way it works, but that's not cool, as I don't need to save it in general case, I added this just for testing purpose

Comment: what type is CurrentImage?...Image?...and what type is  stitching?

Comment: yes, they are both System.Drawing.Image